# Wordpress - Change Location (url) on element change

Tags: php, jquery

I am looking to change a wordpress url when changed.

The trigger is not hard, that is just a .change use of jQuery api. However at the moment I get:

```
?cat=bristol-bristol
```

When I change the value I would like to strip the code below from the url. I have already got this as follows::

```
?cat=
```

Current Script

```
<script>
    var dropdown = $('#element span');

    function ChangeUrl() {

        if ( if element is not empty... ){
            location.href = <?php echo get_option('home');?>/?locations=+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }

    dropdown.onchange = ChangeUrl;
</script>
```

Comment: What results you are expecting?

Comment: This code is really full of errors:
1. missing quotes after location.href
2. Jquery uses che .change method and it needs a function not '='
3. I'm not sure that a 'span' will ever fire a 'change' event

Comment: Apologies it turned out to be an incorrect error in my php $args, I should have done a better example.